# I am building ionic app for first-time when npm.cmd i running I am facing this error

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ytYKwd1WQSBST07nwPFjH'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\SAM-TEC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-24T16_07_36_464Z-debug.log [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

```
npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: whats your node version?

Comment: Can you show us what is the command that you are using to build the app?

Comment: C:\Users\SAM-TEC\Desktop>ionic start app

Comment: Thanks for your interaction I am very suffering from this error

Comment: i am update npm and the result new error

Comment: npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SAM-TEC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-27T22_02_24_579Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.